# Border missing btn-outline-secondary bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with btn-outline-secondary in bootstrap. Once I upload my code to my website the border on the buttons disappears. The border is visible when I view my working HTML in the browser offline.

I've tried over-riding the boostrap CSS and increasing the border thickness - still invisible.

Included two examples of code below:

ONE

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https:imgur"><img>
  <div class="card-body">
   <h6>Title</h6>
   <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
   <a href= "https:..." target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">VIEW</a>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

TWO

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled>Text</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled>Text</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled>Text</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the code causing the problem, it is difficult to know what could be going happening. Are there any differences at all between the online and offline versions?

Comment: @FluffyKitten no differences at all. This code is straight from the HTML file I've uploaded onto the server, and I've removed any CSS amendments and gone with vanilla bootstrap library for these buttons.